# angular-dragdrop: How to empty the drop area after an item has been dropped?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-dragdrop

**THE SITUATION:**

Hello guys. In my app i have a list of items displayed inside a table.

I am using [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) to be able to drag this items to the bin and delete them.

Everything is working fine: after i drop the item over the bin the function is fired and the item is delete.

But there is one problem: **after the item is being deleted, the list of items is refreshed. But what happens is that an item is still in the drop area. And since the deleted item is not part of the list, the following item take its place..**

This item should be displayed in the list and not over the drop area..

**THE CODE:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list_items track by $index">

     <td>
        <span data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, onStart:'set_item_id_to_drag({mail_id: email.mail_id})'}">
        <a > {{item.name}} </a>
        </span>
    </td>

 </tr>

<span data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options jqyoui-droppable="{onDrop:'email_dragged_delete()'}">
    BIN
</span>


$scope.email_dragged_delete = function( event, ui )
{
   var item_id = $rootScope.item_id_to_drag.item_id;
    $http({

        url: base_url + 'api/item_delete',
        data: { item_id: item_id },
        method: "POST",

     }).success(function (data) {

        delete $rootScope.email_id_to_drag;

        var result = ItemsService.list_items( $stateParams.mail_account_id );
        result.then( function( data ) {

            $rootScope.list_items = data;

        });

     });

}

$scope.set_item_id_to_drag = function( event, ui, item_id )
{
    $rootScope.item_id_to_drag = item_id;
}
```

**THE QUESTION:**

**Is it possible to empty the drop area after an element has been dragged and an event has been fired?** 
So to avoid that another element in the list take its place?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you create a demo on JSFiddle or Plunkr? I did not understand it correctly though. Did you try `jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},placeholder:true}`